# How to maintain LINQ deferred execution on SELECT TOP 1

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, lambda

How do I create a LINQ statement that maintains deferred execution when the SQL query contains `select top 1`? I want it to be chainable to other LINQ queries of type IQueryable<>.

```
var query1 = from t in table
             where t.test == 1
             select t;

//this should set query2 of type IQueryable<TableEntity> 
var query2 = from q in query1
             [[SELECT TOP 1 SOMEHOW]]
             select q;

var query3 = from q in query2
             where q.test2 == 2

var executedResult = query3.ToList();
```

Not fussed if the solution uses lambda or linq or both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var query2 = (from q in query1
             select t)
             .Take(1);
```

[Take(count)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns IEnumerable containing `count` elements (or less if it didn't find enough).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Take(1) which returns an IEnumerable. If the source is empty this may return a null. Check these links out for more information...

MSDN source : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In your case

```
var query2 = (from q in query1
         select t)
         .Take(1);
```